# Token symbol is the same thing with metal(MTL)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I built an ERC-20 token named Moontrail and the symbol is the same that Metal (MTL) I am afraid when listing on exchanges and coinmarketcap. Should I leave it or create another one?

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view there can be multiple ERC20 tokens with the same symbol.

It's going to hurt your brand for sure. This is a decision you have to make.

Comment: OK, am worrying about listing on exchanges and coinmarketcap, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same name and symbol, but it's not recommended, especially if you want to list your token. I highly recommend you come up with a different name and symbol to avoid confusion

Comment: Please, do you know how to edit through etherscan

Comment: you can't. etherscan is for viewing and reading from contracts and addresses. once a contract is deployed, it's permanent. you'll need to deploy a new contract